# php stitch images at an angle

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

I did some google searching for few variations of 'php stich images at an angle' on this, but couldn't come up with anything useful.

I need to create a little script where user uploads a single image file (jpg, png or gif). I then need to take this file and stitch it together x number of times (parameter also supplied by user) on its sides making a closed shape.

For example if the x=6 I need to stitch the images together at a 120 degrees to create a hexagon, if you look at the final result from the top.

I really do not know how to even start this one, so unfortunatelly I cannot show any code as of yet.

Thanks for any sugestions and help.

Comment: Start by creating a script where users can upload images. Take a look at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php or so to see if you can figure out how to stitch the image. If you get into trouble, come back with your code and people here will gladly help you solve your problem.

Comment: Are there any limits on the values of `x`? Or could it be 8,675,789? Can you give an example of what you seek? What is supposed to be in the gaps between the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you want, since it forms a circle and not a hexagon. But in ImageMagick command line you can do the following by duplicating the input as many times as you need. (I duplicated it 5 times so a total of 6). Then use distort arc to wrap it into a full circle:

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png -duplicate 5 +append -virtual-pixel White -distort Arc 360  tmp.png
```

[image]

You can also put a spacer between the images as follows:

```
convert lena.png \( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -crop 25x100+0+0% +repage \) +append -duplicate 5 +append -virtual-pixel White -distort Arc 360  tmp.png
```

[image]

Comment: Cool - print your own CD labels for Image Processing enthusiasts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want. Using ImageMagick 6 and bash unix shell scripting. This uses +distort SRT. I start with the center of the image. Then compute where it would be if the image were rotated and placed so the bottom corners were on the circle of the given radius. Then I use +distort SRT to move the center point and to rotate the image by the angle+90, so that it is turned correctly for the position around the circle. I do this in a loop for as many copies you want to use (in this case num=6) incrementing the angle. Once the loop finishes. I combine the tmp files onto a white background using -layers merge to make use of the virtual canvas added to each tmp image according to the position and rotation. Then I remove all the tmp files.

```
infile="lena.png"
num=6
angle=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:360/$num]" info:)
width=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:w]" info:)
height=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:h]" info:)
ix=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$width/2]" info:)
iy=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$height/2]" info:)
radius=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($height/2) + $width/(2*tan((pi/180)*($angle/2)))]" info:)
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
rot1=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$i*$angle]" info:)
rot2=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$rot1+90]" info:)
ox=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($radius+$width)+$radius*cos((pi/180)*$rot1)]" info:)
oy=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($radius+$height)+$radius*sin((pi/180)*$rot1)]" info:)
convert "$infile" -virtual-pixel none +distort SRT "$ix,$iy 1 $rot2  $ox,$oy" tmp_$i.png
done
convert tmp_*.png -background white -layers merge +repage result.png
rm -f tmp_*.png
```

[image]

Here is for num=5 (pentagon):

[image]

Someone who knows Imagick and PHP should be able to convert this for you.